# Bootstrap Layout Full Screen 2 Rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap 3, how do I create a layout that fills the entire screen (100% height) and consists of 2 rows as follows (each 50% height) ? The view should not scroll. Thank you for your help

[image]

I have started with this mark-up but cannot get the results I need:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-lg-12">Top</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-lg-4">Bottem Left</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">Bottom Center</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">Bottom Right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't offer a mechanism to do 100% height layouts. You'll need some custom CSS.

Here's one approach. Your question leaves some things unaddressed, such as what should happen in overflow situations.

```
.row > div {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
.row.one-third {
    height: 33.333%;
}
.row.two-thirds {
    height: 66.667%;
}
```

**[Demo](http://liveweave.com/eVosvk)**

**[Here it is](http://liveweave.com/opgysn)** again with 50% heights.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12"><h4>Top row</h4></div>
 </div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4"><h4>Bottom row col 1</h4></p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4"><h4>Bottom row col 2</h4></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4"><h4>Bottom row col 3</h4></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't work to create a layout that fills the screen - I'm also not sure you should be applying the container class to each div within each row

Comment: it was intended only for styling purposes